# Is it preferred to use teams site or communication site when audience is large?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Suppose my requirement to have a one way communication where in a few authors publish articles that need to be consumed by large audience.

Now this looks more like a communication site scenario, and less like a teams site scenario.

However although I have small set of authors, I want them to be able to collaborate in some way. The solution is either to create a teams site (which comes with mailbox) or to create a private group with the authors for the purpose of collaboration. Which is the preferred option in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, a Communication Site is the preferred option as it is designed for one-way communication to a large audience. You can have a small number of authors who can publish content, and a much larger number of readers who can consume the content. For collaboration among the authors, you can create a private group separate from the Communication Site.

Comment: If I do create a teams site then nothing stops we from adding a large audience. Similarly if I create a communication site then nothing stops me from creating a large number of authors. With the former (team site) I get the group, mailbox as well. What is the harm of choosing the team site?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by large audience, but Teams has a limit of how many people can be in Teams team (hence teamified teams site).
From 10 000 (at mentions) to 25 000, depending on the exact scenario:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams

Additionally, Communication site has some nice features designed specifically for Communication around news which is what you may want for a large audience:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-share-news-on-your-sharepoint-sites-495f8f1a-3bef-4045-b33a-55e5abe7aed7

You probably don't want to communicate with 20000 users through teams posts.

Communication site is also what you want to choose for your Home Site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/viva/connections/home-site-plan

For your scenario I would take Communication site. Manipulate permissions on Site Pages, so that only your selected users can create posts and maybe throw in an approval workflow (out of the box)?